# Will I pass inspection/code if I install walls over carpet in a finished basement for a couple bedrooms?

Tags: basement

Will I pass inspection/code if I install walls over carpet in a finished basement for a

couple bedrooms?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you'd want to do this?

Comment: Would this be inside or outside walls? There could be some code issues it the locations require sheet rock or other material to limit the spread of smoke or fire. Be aware that would also be sealing in moisture, limited to be sure, likely not a code violation, but if the wood is at all wet, that could be a problem for you in the future. Another thing to think of, again, not likely code, but this would be leaving a superhighway for ants and other nasties to go between the rooms.

Answer (score 5):

There is no code or regulation that I know of that putting a piece of carpet between framing and the base (concrete).  However this is really poor workmanship and I could see your local inspector reacting with a raised eyebrow or he could just say he doesn't want it for whatever reason - it is his call.  Also doing something suspect like this would lead me (if I were an inspector) to really really take notice of everything else.

Why would you do it?  Your flooring still has to be retacked and stretched.  What possible benefit are you getting from the floor under the walls?  You could just slice the carpet right in the middle of the wall, roll it back each way and then create your wall.  You could probably get a carpet place to come out and fix the issues for less than $100 - and this could also be a DIY job.

Comment: I've seen several times construction crews for commercial buildings just put walls on existing carpet and leave cleaning up the carpet to be someone else's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a code or regulation, but consider that it *is* required by code to use pressure treated lumber, because non-pressure treated lumber will rot and/or grow mold and eventually make you sick. I'd imagine that carpet would do the same. If not the polyester carpet fibers, then the backing.

I'd cut the carpet and put the pressure-treated lumber on the concrete. **EDIT:** You should still use a sill gasket between the PT lumber and the concrete. If the PT becomes moist it won't rot, but studs sitting on top of it can wick moisture out of the PT wood, and those WILL rot. Which is another reason not to set the wood on the carpet. The carpet will definitely become wet, which will seep into the PT lumber on the bottom then up into the studs via capillary action through the highly porous ends of the studs.

I'd also try to find out what your local building code specifically says, if anything.

Comment: You still shouldn't put the PT right on the concrete, rather you should use a sill gasket between the two.  One benefit to metal framing is that it can't rot.

Comment: Totally agree, thanks @Steve. I edited my response accordingly.

Comment: The carpet would probably cause the PT lumber to rot faster - that would be the big downside of the carpet install with normal framing.  It would hold water much longer than nothing.